# What are the alternatives of a chi square test in testing for changes in categorial data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I have done a survey trying to understand the waste disposal habits of people.

One question is "What proportion of waste paper do you recycle". Another question is "Given a new local policy is enacted, what proportion of waste paper do you recycle."

I have provided the following options to each of the questions: 0 to <10%, 10 to <20%, 20 to <30%, ...  and I just realized that I may have made a bad decision offering "data bins" for people to choose from.

I want to find out whether the policy is effective in encouraging people to recycle paper.

What statistical testing tool can I use? I am thinking about the chi-square distribution, but I think this only shows whether there is a difference, not increase or decrease.

If there isn't any test I can use, I plan to do a chi-square test showing whether there is a difference, plus some other visual aid to show an increase or decrease. How does that sound?

I know this is an awkward question, but since I am a newbie in the world of statistics, I haven't thought carefully about it beforehand. Any answers appreciated.

Comment: How many bins do you have and what is your sample size?

Comment: I have got 10 bins and the sample size is 104

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, I'd rephrase the question to "...what proportion of waste paper *would* you recycle", unless it was a follow-up survey (which it does not sound like it was). Also, bins may not be a bad choice in this situation, if anything there may be too many bins as it is probably difficult to estimate whether one recycles 15 or 25%. You can express these values as means of each respective bin - so if a person chooses 10-20%, 15% is assigned - and do a standard paired comparison: paired t-test or Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test/sign test if data do not meet the assumptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what do you mean by "assumptions"? Does it mean 1) both the before and after data follow a normal distribution, or 2) the difference in before and after data follow a normal distribution or something else?

Comment: yes (1) and that variances are equal in both populations.